# Why can't we integrate functions on a manifold?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, manifolds

Most books about manifolds say that "there is no way to integrate real-valued functions in a coordinate-independent way on a manifold". I've read the usual reasons but they don't seem to differ from the usual theory of integration in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I explain below what I mean.

Let $M$ be an orientable smooth $n$-manifold. Since it is orientable, we have a nonvanishing $n$-form $\omega$. This allows us to define the following linear functional:
\begin{align*}
\Lambda:C_c^{\infty}(M)&\to \mathbb{R}\\
f &\mapsto \int_M f\omega.
\end{align*}
By continuity, we can extend its domain to obtain a positive linear functional $C_c(M)\to \mathbb{R}$. Then, the Riesz-Markov-Kakutani representation theorem implies the existence of a regular Borel measure $\mu$ such that
$$\Lambda(f)=\int_M f \:\mathrm{d}\mu,$$
for all $f\in C_c^\infty(M)$.

Why isn't this a good notion of integral of functions on a manifold? It doesn't seem to depend on a choice of chart and while it depends of a choice of $\omega$, I would argue that the same thing happens in $\mathbb{R}^n$ since the Lebesgue measure depends of a normalization factor.

Comment: How is $\omega$ chosen? The lebesgue measure satisfies the strong property that it is translation-invariant, and so up to a positive real scaling there is really only one lebesgue measure. However, $\omega$ could change from place to place quite wildly; for any positive real _function_ we get a different choice $\omega$.

Comment: Orientations and nonvanishing $n$-forms are basically the same thing. (Proposition 15.5 in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds.) By fixing an orientation of $M$, which we have to do anyway, we get a nonvanishing $n$-form. It does **not** depend on $f$ at all.

Comment: Also, in a manifold being translation-invariant doesn't even make sense, so I don't think we lose anything primordial because of that.

Comment: Orientations and nonvanishing $n$-forms are very much not the same thing!  An orientation exists iff a nonvanishing $n$-form exists, but each orientation comes from many different nonvanishing $n$-forms.

Comment: @EricWofsey sure. But this doesn't change anything in my argument, does it?

Comment: Closely related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1829285/the-integral-of-a-function-on-manifold-and-differential-form/1829292#1829292

Comment: @LeeMosher, there you say that we cannot integrate functions on a manifold because such an integral wouldn't transform correctly under a change of coordinates. I can't see why this would be a problem in the way I've defined the integral.

Comment: You have certainly defined a perfectly good and useful way to assign a linear functional to each nonvanishing $n$-form $\omega$. But the raw fact that the linear functional depends heavily on $\omega$ is, in my mind, an instance of the principle that the integral does not transform correctly under a change of coordinates. In this case, if you change $\omega$ then you change the integral, unless you throw in a change-of-coordinates factor, namely a Radon-Nykodym derivative. So it really is the same thing as in my other answer.

Comment: Let $\omega$ be a choice of nonvanishing top form, and $f: M \to (0,\infty)$ any smooth positive-valued function. Then $\omega$ and $f\omega$ yield different notions of integration, and _a priori_ (ie given only the manifold $M$) there is no way to choose between them. Contrast this to the case where $\omega$ is the lebesgue measure, then $f \omega$ will be translation invariant only if $f$ is a _constant_ function.