# Application of the fundamental theorem of calculus in $n$ dimensions: Stokes', divergence or gradient theorem?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, stokes-theorem, divergence-theorem

Consider the following linear integral solved by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:
$$\int_{a_1}^{a_2}dx\, e^{ixk}=\int_{a_1}^{a_2}dx\, \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{e^{ixk}}{ik}\right)= \frac{e^{ixk}}{ik}\Biggr\rvert_{a_1}^{a_2}=\frac{e^{ia_2 k}- e^{i a_1 k}}{ik}\,.$$
Is there a way to make use of a generalization of this theorem in $n$ dimensions (maybe the Gradient Theorem, or Divergence Theorem, or Stokes' theorem?) such that the multidimensional integral defined over a $n$-dimensional generic volume $V$
$$\int_{V}d\mathbf{x}\, e^{i\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{k}}$$
is solved in terms of the integrand function evalutated at the $(n-1)$-dimensional boundary surface $\partial V$ of the volume $V$:
$$\int_{V}d\mathbf{x}\, e^{i\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{k}}=\int_V d\mathbf{x}\, \nabla_{\mathbf{x}}(e^{i\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{k}})\cdot \frac{\mathbf{k}}{i k^2} \propto e^{i\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{k}}\rvert_{\mathbf{x}\in \partial V}\, ?$$
Indeed in the linear example above, the integral solution is expressed in terms of the exponential function appearing in the argument, evaluated at the two points corresponding to the borders $x=a_1, a_2$ of the linear domain $[a_1,a_2]$.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is known as the [(Generalized) Stokes Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Stokes_theorem). It is stated in the language of [differential forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form).

A good introductory treatment can be found in Spivak's little book [Calculus on Manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_on_Manifolds_(book)).

Very briefly, the integrands of classical vector calculus in 3-space, such as $dA \cdot \vec n$ for surface integrals or $dV$ for volume integrals, generalize to differential 2-forms and 3-forms respectively, and then to differential $k$-forms for any dimension $k \ge 1$. When you integrate over a "$k$-dimensional generic volume" as you put it, or over a "$k$-dimensional oriented manifold" in the new language, [the thing that you integrate is a differential $k$-form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1829285/the-integral-of-a-function-on-manifold-and-differential-form/1829292#1829292). The differential operators of classical vector calculus, i.e. [div, grad, curl and all that](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/703104.Div_Grad_Curl_and_All_That), generalize to an operator called the [exterior derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form#The_exterior_derivative), or sometimes just the "differential", denoted $d$, which (for $k \ge 0$) inputs a differential $k$-form $\omega$ and outputs a differential $k+1$ form denoted $d\omega$.

Once all those prerequisites are developed (which takes most of Spivak's book), the generalized Stokes theorem then has a very simple formulation:
$$\int_M d \, \omega = \int_{\partial M} \omega
$$
where $M$ is a compact, oriented, $k$-dimensional manifold, $\partial M$ is its boundary which is a compact, oriented $k-1$-dimensional manifold, and $\omega$ is a $k-1$ form.

Comment: Thank you very much. So in relation to my problem, we can conclude that $\int_V d\mathbf{x}\, e^{i\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{k}}\propto \int_{\partial V}d \mathbf{y}\, e^{i \mathbf{y}\cdot \mathbf{k}}$, with $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ being respectively $n$-dimensional and $(n-1)$-dimensional vectors?

Comment: That does not look like a correct expression. The $\partial V$ integrand should be expressed as a differential $(n-1)$-form, which it currently is not. It's seems very doubtful to me whether your expression can even be re-expressed in the correct fashion (I don't even really know what your expression means). So my best advice is: learn differential forms!