Transformation Formula for distinct Dimensions?
I am currently dealing with an integral for which I am not sure whether I can apply a transformation formula. The situation is essentially the following. Let $T\in\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb R^2, \mathbb R^3)$ be injective, i.e. $\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{im}(T))=2$, and let $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^3$ be integrable.
My goal is to calculate $\int_{\operatorname{im}(T)}f$. Of course if I take the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb R^3$, i.e. $\lambda^3$, this is $0$ since $\lambda^3(\operatorname{im}(T)) = 0$. But what I would really like to do is somehow compute the integral w.r.t. $\lambda^2$ on this $2$-dimensional subspace $\operatorname{im}(T)$.
Questions How does one usually do that? How would that measure be defined? Is there some sort of transformation formula for this, as $T$ is injective? And how would that work, since the Jacobian of $T$ is not a square matrix and hence we can't compute its determinant...
I guess the task is really defining w.r.t. which measure space we have $f\in L^1$, s.t. one has a transformation formula, but I don't know how to do that.
Any help/reference is appreciated.

I guess this is related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1829285/the-integral-of-a-function-on-manifold-and-differential-form

Any affine subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ inherits a version of Lebesgue measure which is uniquely specified by the fact that the measure of a "hyperrectangle" is the product of the lengths of its sides. You can integrate with respect to this measure. Concretely, find an orthonormal basis of $\text{im}(T)$ and use this to define a measure-preserving isomorphism to $\mathbb{R}^2$.
